# Hyperlink VBA Image Userform

Tags: image, excel, vba, hyperlink, userform

I am trying to add an hyperlink that it is loaded when the user clicks on an image located in a userform.

I have tried until now

```
Private Sub Image1_click()

follow.hyperlink address:="www.google.com"

End Sub
```

when I run the above code, it said "error variable not defined"

I really appreciate the help. :D

Comment: what is `follow`? I suspect you need to instead create an instance of Internet Explorer, and use the `Navigate` method. Or you can do this IIRC with IWebBrowser2 control within Excel.  Which do you want -- and where do you want the hyperlink to load???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```